# Conditional Probability where conditioning is on multiple variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, chain-rule

Within Murphy's book Machine Learning: A probabilistic perspective, on page 77 he writes the following:

$p(\theta|D', D'') \propto p(D''|\theta)p(\theta|D')$

Where $D' and D''$ are data sets and $\theta$ the parameter. I have an understanding of the chain rule of probabilities but am stumped here as to how this is formulated

I wonder how this result was achieved? If someone could explain I would be very grateful

Book link: [https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/MLbook/](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/MLbook/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chain rule for probabilities states that
$$p(\theta , D' , D'') = p(D''|\theta, D')p(\theta \: |D')p(D')$$
Now usually in a Bayesian setup we assume that data is conditionally independent on the parameter $\theta$, which means that $p(D',D''|\theta) = p(D'| \theta)p(D'' | \theta)$, and it implies that $p(D'' | \theta , D') = p(D'' | \theta)$.

Now we have that
\begin{align*}
p(\theta | D',D'') &\propto p(\theta \: , D', D'') \\
&=p(D'' | \theta)p(\theta | D')p(D') \\
&\propto p(D''|\theta)p(\theta|D')
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for this. I think I struggled to make the jump that $p(D', D''|\theta) = p(D'|\theta)(D''|\theta)$ even though it makes sense the datasets are independent I did not want to make that jump prematurely. Equivalently, we could also have written this the other way round $\propto p(D'|\theta)p(\theta|D'')$ am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct it also works the other way around.